# An h3 element is not filling a div with a horizontal scroll bar correctly

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Here are two snap shots of the problem.

[image: Normal]

[image: Scrolled]

See how the yellow background of the h3 is cut off?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/CbPWM/1/)

Here is the code:

```
    <style>
        .OutputDiv {
            background-color: lightcyan;
            overflow: auto;
            border: solid 2px black;
            width: 500px;
        }

        h3 {
            margin-top: 0px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="OutputDiv">
        <h3>My Title is Here</h3>
        <pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
               </pre>
    </div>
```

I know I could probably add another div with a background color to contain the h3, but the h3 is a block level element.

Any ideas?

Comment: `h3` is ok , `pre` causes the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `<pre>` is a block level element, the behavior of it's content is different in this case. Since the content must maintain the line breaks and spaces, the `<pre>` tag uses the attribute `white-space: pre;` by default. In your case, both the `<pre>` and `<h3>` elements behave like block elements, so their width is set by their parent. However, the *text* inside the `<pre>` element doesn't follow these rules and overflows, causing the scrollbar to show up on the parent.

In case the you're just using the pre tag for monospace font, you can apply a `white-space: normal` rule to the `<pre>` element.

Otherwise, if this HTML structure isn't a requirement, you can add the `overflow: auto` to the `<pre>` element instead, and remove it from the wrapper element.

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
In case you want the *entire* div to be scrollable, add a wrapper div around the `<h3>` and `<pre>`, and set it's display to `inline-block`. This will force the inner wrapper to take it's width from it's content, and will also force the block level `<h3>` to match this width. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbPWM/12/) for a demo. This does introduce a vertical scrollbar, but removing the `margin-bottom` from the `<pre>` should fix that.

**Edit 2:** Yup, here's the [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbPWM/13/).

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can solve your problem by defining the width of your `h3 tag`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CbPWM/7/)

Alternatively, you can use

```
pre{white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

but this is not showing scroll bar as pre-wrap cathes 100% width and after then it shifts the word below the line.

**Correct Way**

remove `overflow: auto;` from your main div and add `overflow: auto;` to pre

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CbPWM/11/)

**Note:**

As pre tag is overwhelming the width 100% the h3 tag is showing the space in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can either solve your problem by defining the width for h3 tag or including the 
 tags in between text given in  element.